# Can I use "turmoil" here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> Tommy is in a fight with a man, ending with Tommy knocking him out. He then flees out of the restroom and collides with a security guard, who's heard the **turmoil**.

I don't which word I can use here? Does "turmoil" work perfectly? (I have consulted a dictionary, but I'm still not sure)

Comment: May be **fuss**, I don't know for sure

Answer (score 1):

Try "ruckus" or "hubbub" or "commotion" (depending on whether a casual tone is permissible) - turmoil has a more serious connotation

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to hope this answer will be useful for many other similar questions. Here's how I went about putting it together...

> 1: Google **synonym turmoil**
> 2: Compare the relative frequency of several of the synonyms returned...
> ...run [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=turmoil%2Cconfusion%2Cupheaval%2Cturbulence%2Ctumult%2Cdisorder%2Ccommotion&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cturmoil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconfusion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cupheaval%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cturbulence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctumult%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisorder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommotion%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cturmoil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconfusion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cupheaval%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cturbulence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctumult%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisorder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommotion%3B%2Cc0) on... **turmoil,confusion,upheaval,turbulence,tumult,disorder,commotion**
> 3: Select some synonyms that are at least as common as the original target ***turmoil***
> 4: Run NGram to compare some common short phrase, such as **heard the XXX**
> (using several search texts with different values for XXX, as selected from the first NGram)
> 5: Pat yourself on the back [if you get a "clear winner"...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heard%20the%20commotion%2Cheard%20the%20turmoil%2Cheard%20the%20turbulence%2Cheard%20the%20disorder%2Cheard%20the%20confusion&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheard%20the%20commotion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheard%20the%20turmoil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheard%20the%20turbulence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheard%20the%20confusion%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

I can't "explain" why ***commotion*** has such strong associations with sound / noise - but even though I as a native speaker *fully expected* that result, it seems to me anyone else could follow my "recipe" above and reach the same conclusion with just as much confidence as I would have had even without the chart.

Comment: The only quibble I'd have is with the use of "turmoil" as the root - I'd have started with "fight", which would give you brawl, fracas, melee, row, rumpus, confrontation, skirmish,
exchange, struggle, tussle, scuffle & altercation to compare, although not the one that came to my mind - "disturbance".  I've not posted as a separate answer, as I've no issue with the rest of it.

Comment: It seems to me that _turmoil_ refers to the fact of the fight rather than the noise made by it.

Comment: @GwynEvans: But I think I *had* to start with "turmoil", specifically because that was OP's initial candidate word. It's also relevant that *as a native speaker* (and one with a particular interest in this sort of thing) I was already pretty sure what I would get from an NGram for **heard the * and came.** A link to that NGram is too long to fit into a comment, but ***commotion*** comes *way* out front on that one (followed by ***noise, news, sound,...***). But I couldn't just arbitrarily include the clinching ***and came** [running]*  in my example, because a learner couldn't "copy" that.